# No difference between curl_easy and curl_multi

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm performing HTTP requests from my C++ program to my PHP script with libcurl.
The first easy_ version below works good, however it is quite slow (12 requests per second on localhost).
 Nothing strange - I got similar results using `ab -n 1000 -c 1`. 
On the other hand `ab -n 1000 -c 100` performs much more better with 600 request per second.
The thing is, using libcurl multi doesn't seem to be concurrent. I used just slightly modified example code and the result is also about 12 req/s.

Do I understand curl_multi right? How can I achieve results similar to ab? 
PS. I know that both codes are a bit different, however almost whole time is spent on curl work.

**The easy_ way:**

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode response;              // HTTP response

curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl)
{


    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/process.php");

    while(true)
    {
        if(!requestsQueue.empty())              
        {
            mtx.lock();
            string data = requestsQueue.front();                                            
            requestsQueue.pop();
            mtx.unlock();

            const char *post = data.c_str();                                    //convert string to char used by CURL

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post);                   

            do
            {
                response = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            } while(response != CURLE_OK);

        }
        else
        {
            //there are no request to perform, so wait for them
            cout << "Sleeping...\n";
            sleep(2);
            continue;
        }
    }

    //curl_easy_cleanup(curl);          
}
else
{
    cout << "CURL init failed!\n";
}
```

**The multi way:**

```
CURLM *multi_handle;
int still_running; /* keep number of running handles */

/* init a multi stack */
multi_handle = curl_multi_init();

/* add the individual transfers */
for(int i=1;i<=300;i++)
{
    CURL *handle;
    handle = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/process.php");
    curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, handle);
}

 /* we start some action by calling perform right away */
  curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);

 do {
struct timeval timeout;
int rc; /* select() return code */

fd_set fdread;
fd_set fdwrite;
fd_set fdexcep;
int maxfd = -1;

long curl_timeo = -1;

FD_ZERO(&fdread);
FD_ZERO(&fdwrite);
FD_ZERO(&fdexcep);

/* set a suitable timeout to play around with */
timeout.tv_sec = 1;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

curl_multi_timeout(multi_handle, &curl_timeo);
if(curl_timeo >= 0) {
  timeout.tv_sec = curl_timeo / 1000;
  if(timeout.tv_sec > 1)
    timeout.tv_sec = 1;
  else
    timeout.tv_usec = (curl_timeo % 1000) * 1000;
}

/* get file descriptors from the transfers */
curl_multi_fdset(multi_handle, &fdread, &fdwrite, &fdexcep, &maxfd);

/* In a real-world program you OF COURSE check the return code of the
   function calls.  On success, the value of maxfd is guaranteed to be
   greater or equal than -1.  We call select(maxfd + 1, ...), specially in
   case of (maxfd == -1), we call select(0, ...), which is basically equal
   to sleep. */

rc = select(maxfd+1, &fdread, &fdwrite, &fdexcep, &timeout);

switch(rc) {
case -1:
  /* select error */
  break;
case 0:
default:
  /* timeout or readable/writable sockets */
  curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);
  break;
}
} while(still_running);

curl_multi_cleanup(multi_handle);

curl_easy_cleanup(http_handle);

return 0;
```

Comment: I have only used curl in very basic setups, but are you sure `curl_easy_setopt` is the right thing when using `curl_multi...`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: yes. Please note that the URL is an option of easy handle, not multi. Every request could be to different URLs.

Comment: @user2461440 don't call `mutex.lock` and `mutex.unlock` directly use a block and [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) to be exception safe.

Answer (score 3):

curl_multi does indeed work with any amount of transfers in parallel, but it does so using the same single thread for all the work. It has the side-effect that if something anywhere takes a long time, that action blocks all other transfers.

One example of such a blocking operation that sometimes is what causes something like what you're describing, is the name resolver phase if the old blocking name resolver is used. Other explanations include a callback implemented by the application takes time for some reason.

You can build libcurl to instead use c-ares or the threaded-resolver backends that both avoid this blocking behavior and instead much better allow for concurrency. **The threaded resolver is default in libcurl** since many years now (late 2021).

Comment: is it also applicable to localhost connections, which is my case?

Comment: Ah right, sloppy reading of me. Probably not. A localhost "resolve" is likely to be very fast but it all depends on your config. Try using plain IP-numbers for a test and see if there's a speed difference.

Comment: it's just standard debian 7. I'll test it in the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing really changed using 127.0.0.1